# Cannot use import statement outside a module in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, importerror

I was going through this tutorial and the person got there canvas to be black, when I did it, and I did actually what the person has done, nothing happened. So I kept looking seeing what was wrong. And it kept giving me the error for

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

So I looked up what this could be and they said I need to get jquery, so I did and it said about importing the $. I did this and I keep getting importing error.

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I tried all I could but nothing helps. Here is the code that I have

Javascript

```
import $ from "jquery";
var $ = require("jquery");

var Context = {
    canvas: null,
    context: null,
    create: function(canvas_tag_id) {
        this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_tag_id);
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        return this.context;
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    // Initialize
    Context.create("canvas");

    Context.context.beginPath();
    Context.context.rect(0, 0, 1250, 650);
    Context.context.fillStyle = 'black';
    Context.context.fill();

});
```

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <title>Hellcraze</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="1250" height="640"
            style="border: 1px solid grey; width: 1250px; height: 640px;"
        ></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: The title should give a short summary of the problem and not a tale of woe. How should anybody anticipate what the problem might be with such a title?

Comment: I ran the code you have above without the require or the import and it works fine. You are trying to import jquery when you import the library in your html

Comment: Like pointed out you don't even need to use the `import` seen as your importing yourself using the html file, and the `require` is common.js format that browsers don't support.  Saying that, the `import` shouldn't error on modern browsers, but you don't mention what browser your trying this on.

Comment: so I did that I removed the require and import, and it shows this error .       


`$(document).ready(function() {
^

ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jk/Desktop/Webpage/main.js:11:1)`

I'm using Chrome browser

Comment: remove `type="module"` from the HTML. Your JS file doesn't appear to actually be a module. Do you understand about ES6 modules?

Comment: not really I should try and learn more but I guess I should watch a video. But I will remove it.